# Changing NaN values to 0 based on the value on other column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change `NaN` values from one column based on the value of another column.

**First table**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 0 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN |
| 4 | 2 |

**Targeted table**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 2 | NaN |
| 4 | 2 |

So I want to change NaN to 0, if the value of column A in that row is also 0.

The python code that I create:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'A'] == 0 and math.isnan(df.loc[i,'B']) = True:
        df.loc[i,'B'] = 0
```

But this code seems so slow, because I want to do this for 20 million rows. Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First combine the conditions using `&` (element-wise `and` operator):

```py
conditions = df['B'].isnull() & df['A'].eq(0)

# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3    False
# dtype: bool
```

Then you can vectorize the assignment (no loop):

- Either use a single `loc`:

  ```py
  df.loc[conditions, 'B'] = 0
  ```
- Or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the values that satisfy those conditions with 0:

  ```py
  df['B'] = df['B'].mask(conditions, 0)
  ```

Output:

```
#    A    B
# 0  2  3.0
# 1  0  0.0
# 2  2  NaN
# 3  4  2.0
```

Comment: I've tried to do this, but when I call df again it doesn't change and stays NaN

Comment: @el-cheapo you mean with the sample dataframe or your real data?

Comment: Now that works, thank you!

Comment: great, you're welcome!